# AWS Cloudformation - Enable AWS Loadbalancer cookie stickiness

Tags: amazon-web-services, cookies, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I found couple resources, that describes how to enable AWS ELB cookie stickiness. They all say, that I need only to add to Loadbalancer properties "LBCookieStickinessPolicy" with same policy name that exist in "Listeners", like that:

```
"LBCookieStickinessPolicy" : [{
  "PolicyName" : "ELBSecurityPolicy",
  "CookieExpirationPeriod" : "0"
}],
"Listeners" : [{
  "InstanceProtocol": "HTTPS",
  "LoadBalancerPort": "443",
  "Protocol": "HTTPS",
  "InstancePort": "443",
  "PolicyNames": ["ELBSecurityPolicy"],
  "SSLCertificateId": "arn:aws:iam::accountId:server-certificate/cloudfront/NetSslCert"
}]
```

It fails for me, with error:

> CREATE_FAILED AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer Policy names
>   starting with [ELBSample-, ELBSecurityPolicy] are reserved

As I understand, creation failed, because it trying to create new policy. And it policy name already exist. So what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix that?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create a resource with `ELBSecurityPolicy` name - and this name is reserved for AWS purposes. As the Error message says ;-)

Comment: As I mentioned, I understand what error means, but still don't understand what the proper way to do that?

Comment: Just rename your current `ELBSecurityPolicy` resource?

Comment: Ok, now I does creting resources, but not enabling Loadbalancer cookie stickiness. Any advise?